# Using .NET Web service in Android - parsing the returned XML

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing, asmx, android-ksoap2

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462399/android-and-net-webservice-parsing-the-returned-xml) post FROSTYSMOOTH ask a question and himself answered his question, this is very clear code, but i can't find using web service in his reformed code. how handle in reformed code these line in his first code?

```
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.ces.org/android/android.asmx";//must point to where service is located


/** HelloAndroid method */
//SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHODNAME
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloAndroid";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloAndroid";


/** SelectInstitutionTypes method */
//SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHODNAME
private static final String SOAP_ACTION_INSTITUTIONS = "http://tempuri.org/SelectInstitutionTypes";
private static final String METHOD_NAME_INSTITUTIONS = "SelectInstitutionTypes";


/** SelectPrograms method */
//SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHODNAME
private static final String SOAP_ACTION_PROGRAMS = "http://tempuri.org/SelectPrograms";
private static final String METHOD_NAME_PROGRAMS = "SelectPrograms";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    getHelloAndroid();
    //getInstitutionTypes();
    getPrograms();

}//end of onCreate
```

Comment: Is this the complete code?

Comment: i don't know ,please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462399/android-and-net-webservice-parsing-the-returned-xml